# How am I supposed to avoid this kind of code?

Tags: c#, code-cleanup

How to avoid this kind of coding?

I don't know what kind of query to put all the stored value in the database into the their desired textboxes.

And how to exclude fields in the database table? I got 50 fields in my table and I only want like 45 of them to be displayed in the texboxes, so in the future I don't like to code it manually, I want to avoid coding like this its ugly, is there any shortcut to code them excludingly?

```
  void grdViewStudents_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (grdViewStudents.SelectedRows.Count == 1)
        {
                 dtpDate.Value.ToLongTimeString()
                 txtFamName.Text=cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["FamilyName"].ToString();
                 txtFirstName.Text=cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["FamilyName"].ToString();
                 txtMidName.Text=cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["FamilyName"].ToString();
                 txtSchoolID.Text=cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["FamilyName"].ToString();
                 cmbCourse.Text=cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["FamilyName"].ToString();
                 cmbMajor.Text=cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["FamilyName"].ToString();
                 cmbYear.Text=cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["FamilyName"].ToString();
                 dtpBirthday.Value.ToShortDateString()
                 cmbSem.Text=cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["FamilyName"].ToString();
                 txtSY.Text=cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["FamilyName"].ToString();
                 txtSum.Text=cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["FamilyName"].ToString();
                 cmbGender.Text=cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["FamilyName"].ToString();
                 cmbCivil.Text=cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["FamilyName"].ToString();
                 txtNationality.Text=cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["FamilyName"].ToString();
                 txtHomeAdd.Text=cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["FamilyName"].ToString();
                 txtPermaAdd.Text=cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["FamilyName"].ToString();
                 txtContact.Text=cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["FamilyName"].ToString();
                 txtEmailAdd.Text=cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["FamilyName"].ToString();
                 cmbReligion.Text=cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["FamilyName"].ToString();
                 cmbStudentStatus.Text=cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["FamilyName"].ToString();
                 txtSchoolLast.Text=cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["FamilyName"].ToString();
                 txtTerm.Text=cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["FamilyName"].ToString();
                 txtAcadYR.Text=cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["FamilyName"].ToString();
                 txtScholar.Text=cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["FamilyName"].ToString();
                 txtFather.Text=cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["FamilyName"].ToString();
                 txtFatherAdd.Text=cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["FamilyName"].ToString();
                 txtFatherJob.Text=cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["FamilyName"].ToString();
                 txtMother.Text =cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["FamilyName"].ToString();
                 txtMotherAdd.Text=cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["FamilyName"].ToString();
                 txtMotherJob.Text=cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["FamilyName"].ToString();
                 txtGuardianName.Text=cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["FamilyName"].ToString();
                 txtGuardianRelation.Text=cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["FamilyName"].ToString();
                 txtGuardianContact.Text=cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["FamilyName"].ToString();
                 txtGuardianAdd.Text=cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["FamilyName"].ToString();
                 txtRespPerson.Text=cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["FamilyName"].ToString();
                 txtRespPersonRelation.Text=cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["FamilyName"].ToString();
                 txtRespPersonAdd.Text=cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["FamilyName"].ToString();
                 txtRespPersonContact.Text=cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["FamilyName"].ToString();
                 txtEmployerName.Text=cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["FamilyName"].ToString();
                 txtEmployerAdd.Text=cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["FamilyName"].ToString();
                 txtElemName.Text=cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["FamilyName"].ToString();
                 txtElemAdd.Text=cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["FamilyName"].ToString();
                 dtpElemYear.Value.ToString("yyyy")
                 txtHiSkulName.Text=cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["FamilyName"].ToString();
                 txtHiSkulAdd.Text=cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["FamilyName"].ToString();
                 dtpHiSkulYear.Value.ToString("yyyy")
                 txtCollegeName.Text=cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["FamilyName"].ToString();
                 txtCollegeAdd.Text=cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["FamilyName"].ToString();
                 dtpCollegeYear.Value.ToString("yyyy")
        }
    }
```

Comment: does all the textboxes hold same value?

Comment: You can store it in `object` instead of assigning directly into `TextBox`

Comment: may be  `angularjs with asp.net `

Comment: @ M.kazem Akhgary no they don't hold the same value, the name of the textbox are different

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar this doesn't look like a web project to me.

Comment: You don't have to repeat yourself with `cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]` - assign it to a variable. I'm assuming FamilyName should change. Add spaces. Align the right sides of the assignments. Create a wrapper function that just takes the column name (like FamilyName) and then returns the text.

Answer (score 1):

you can use entityframework to avoid this kind of coding .